# Inverse Trig Equation with Function in Argument

Tags: equations

I'm trying to automate a report to allow me to change a could of variables defined at the top, which will cascade into the document with updated numbers.

My issue is with trying to calculate inverse trig functions where the argument of the function is actually another equation (see the screenshot). (I think the \def is just a string that, when put into tikz, gets evaluated.)

[image]

Can someone help me either:

1. Evaluate the equation (argument) to another variable to resolve to a single number, or
2. Describe how to properly embed the equation into the inverse trig function, or
3. Help with another method?

You'll see in the MWE below that I want to use \ARCSIN from the calculator package. Is there a better one to use?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{trig}

\begin{document}

%% Defined Variables
\def\CrankAngle{170} % Angle position of the crank for piston dynamics
\def\Stroke{60} % Piston stroke, which is equivalent to crank working diameter
\def\ConRodLength{100} % Length of connecting rod
\def\PistonOffset{25} % L_o - offset of the piston cylinder from the crank centerline

%% Derived Variables (Calculated from Defined Variables)
\CalculateCos{\CrankAngle} % Need to pre-calculate the value before using
\def\StrokeXPos{\UseCos{\CrankAngle}*\Stroke/2} % Assign the value of the recently-calculated sin to a global variable MUST DO

\CalculateSin{\CrankAngle} % Need to pre-calculate the value before using
\def\StrokeYPos{\UseSin{\CrankAngle}*\Stroke/2} % Assign the value of the recently-calculated sin to a global variable MUST DO

\def\ConRodYOffset{\PistonOffset -\StrokeYPos}

\def\ConRodSinRatio{\ConRodYOffset/\ConRodLength}

%\ARCSIN{\ConRodSinRatio}{\sol} - WHAT TO USE THIS (OR SIMILAR) BUT NEED NUMBER IN RATIO; NOT EXPRESSION


\section{Sample Evaluations}

X-Position = \StrokeXPos

Y-Position = \StrokeYPos

Con Rod Y-Offset = \ConRodYOffset

Con Rod Sin Ratio = \ConRodSinRatio

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always used `pgf` for calculations and seems to work great:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% For {align*}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

%% Defined Variables
\def\CrankAngle{170} % Angle position of the crank for piston dynamics
\def\Stroke{60} % Piston stroke, which is equivalent to crank working diameter
\def\ConRodLength{100} % Length of connecting rod
\def\PistonOffset{25} % L_o - offset of the piston cylinder from the crank centerline

%% Derived Variables (Calculated from Defined Variables)
\pgfmathsetmacro\StrokeXPos{cos(\CrankAngle)*\Stroke/2} % Assign the value of the recently-calculated sin to a global variable MUST DO

\pgfmathsetmacro\StrokeYPos{sin(\CrankAngle)*\Stroke/2} % Assign the value of the recently-calculated sin to a global variable MUST DO

\pgfmathsetmacro\ConRodYOffset{\PistonOffset -\StrokeYPos}

\pgfmathsetmacro\ConRodSinRatio{\ConRodYOffset/\ConRodLength}

\pgfmathsetmacro\ArcSinValue{asin(\ConRodSinRatio)} 


\section{Sample Evaluations}

\begin{align*}
    \text{X-Position} &= \StrokeXPos \\
    \text{Y-Position} &= \StrokeYPos \\
    \text{Con Rod Y-Offset} &= \ConRodYOffset \\
    \text{Con Rod Sin Ratio} &= \ConRodSinRatio \\
    \text{Arc Sin Value} &= \ArcSinValue \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sweet!!! Thanks Peter. I knew it had to be that easy. :)